# How to create complex Integration Test with 2 Web API using C# (NUnit)?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, testing, integration-testing

I have an application that works as shown on the figure:

[image: My app scheme]

The idea behind is:

Both Web API (`Web API #1`, `Web API #2`) are part of my application (2 projects in 1 solution).

**step 1**: Requesting the endpoint of `Web API #1`. `Web API #1` stores a record to database with status `NEW`.

**step 2**: `Web API #1` returns a response to a caller (For example: Your request has been accepted).

**step 3**: `Web API #1` has a demon inside. The demon sees a new record in the database with status `NEW` and make a request to `Web API #2`.

**step 4**: `Web API #2` do some work (For example: 10 seconds) and returns a response to `Web API #1`. `Web API #1` updated the record in database with status `PROCESSED`.

I know how to test the endpoint of `Web API #1` (`WebApplicationFactory` etc...), but I want to test full cycle: request to `Web API #1` -> record with status `NEW` -> request to `Web API #2` -> response -> record with status `Processed` -> We have record with status `PROCESSED`? => **Test is done**.

Comment: One way to do it is to create a method on Web API #1 to check progress. Because this is an async operation, you must account for the processing time in your test. Here's one more idea. You can setup the database for a call to Web API #2, test it in "isolation" and combine that with a unit test that checks that Web API #1 does indeed call Web API #2 when it should.

Comment: @maxbeaudoin this makes sense. I have implemented test case for the full cycle test and one thing bothers me. When I requested endpoint for `Web API #1`, I received response immediately, after that I have to wait when status will be changed from `NEW` to `PROCESSED` in the database. I am using infinitive loop to check status. Is there way to be notified or something? Or infinitive loop is the only solution for this kind of cases?